# Try Catch in PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a problem with my Try Catch in the Page_Load method. The Catch should take effect, if the Session is NULL, but it does not before I press "Continue" in Visual Studio. But then everything works the way it should. Do you have any ideas what could be the problem?

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=VulnerableApp;Integrated Security=True");
 try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand validation = new SqlCommand();
            validation.Connection = conn;
            validation.CommandText = "Select Role From Users Where Username ='" + Session["Username"] + "';";
            string rank = (string)validation.ExecuteScalar();

            if (rank.Trim() == "Admin" || rank.Trim() == "Moderator")
            {
                lblAdmin.Text = "Welcome " + (string)Session["Username"];
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your rank is to low " + rank);
                Response.Redirect("Done.aspx");
            }conn.Close();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to be logged in");
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: B ecause the debugger stops on all exceptions (thrown, as well as user unhandled). You can change that setting. How to do it depends on your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: This is an abuse of try/catch. If you want to determine if a user is logged in or not, then you shouldn't need to use an exception to accomplish this. Check the Session variable to see if it's populated.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=VulnerableApp;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand validation = new SqlCommand();
                validation.Connection = conn;
                validation.CommandText = "Select Role From Users Where Username ='" + Session["Username"] + "';";
                string rank = (string)validation.ExecuteScalar();

                if (rank.Trim() == "Admin" || rank.Trim() == "Moderator")
                {
                    lblAdmin.Text = "Welcome " + (string)Session["Username"];
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your rank is to low " + rank);
                    Response.Redirect("Done.aspx");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have to be logged in" + ex.Message);
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation how your solution works.